# C: function to read a token from stdin

Tags: c, programming-challenge, strings

I recently started doing some competitive programming in C and one of my first requirements was a high-speed token reader (analogous to the java `Scanner` class' `next()` function). A few examples of input I am most likely to read are:

```
5
ccadd
bddcc
```

```
5 4 1
1 2 5
2 3 7
3 4 8
4 5 2
2 3
```

The integer/float inputs will be handled using `atoi()` and `atof()`, so all I need to develop is a function that will read words from `stdin`. Here's the first prototype:

```
#define BUF_SIZE (1 << 10) // approx 2 KiB or 1024 chars

char* next_token() {
    char* buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    char cc;
    // consume leading whitespaces
    while (isspace(cc=getchar())) ;
    buf[0] = cc;
    int i=1;
    int nofs = 1;
    while (!isspace(cc=getchar())) {
        if (i >= BUF_SIZE*nofs) {
            // gracefully extend buffer size
            nofs++;
            buf = realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE*nofs*sizeof(char));
        }
        buf[i] = cc;
        i++;
    }
    // trim buffer
    buf = realloc(buf, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    int T = atoi(next_token());
    while (T-- > 0) {
        char* word = next_token();
        // more logic here
    }
}
```

Two questions I had with this code are:

1. Is this fast enough? I think the major bottleneck lies with the `realloc` at the end, where I trim the length. If it's not fast enough, please suggest some optimizations.
2. Is this compliant with how C is generally written? I'm coming from Java and have little  experience with C code. I write some embedded C but that's closer to assembly than it is to this type of code.

Any further improvements are welcome.

Comment: How fast is _fast enough_? Do you have any measurable requirements?

Comment: Can you quote the original programming challenge? Otherwise I don't consider this particularly off-topic, as long as this represents the solution in its entirety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Alignment

This will be an easy win - use `aligned_alloc` instead of `malloc`. This is only guaranteed to be available in the standard library as of C11, which you should be using anyway.

### Exponential reallocation

This:

```
        // gracefully extend buffer size
        nofs++;
        buf = realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE*nofs*sizeof(char));
```

reallocates with linear growth. Memory is cheap and CPU time is expensive, so reallocate with exponential growth instead. Choosing a growth factor is a little more involved, but growth factors of 1.5 or 2 are not uncommon.

### Inner assignment

Remove the assignment-in-condition from this:

```
while (isspace(cc=getchar())) ;
```

It does not make anything faster, and is a nasty bit of C syntax that makes code more difficult to read, maintain and debug.

### Use a `for`

```
int i=1;
while (!isspace(cc=getchar())) {
    // ...
    i++;
}
```

can be

```
for (int i = 1; !isspace(cc); i++) {
   // ...
   cc = getchar();
}
```

noting that an initial `getchar()` would need to precede this loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using C11 is not an option - I have to stick with C99. Also, why the preference for `for` over `while`? K&R seems to use inner assignment similar to what I have done.

Comment: _Using C11 is not an option_ - Fine; there are other options to do aligned allocation; I will leave this as an exercise to you. _K&R seems to use inner assignment_ - That doesn't mean that it's a good idea :) Modern practice is to discourage such a pattern, and most languages do not support such a thing for good reason.

Comment: _why the preference for for over while?_ - Because in this case you have a loop counter, and a `for` is designed specifically to frame that situation.

Comment: Why didn't you mention checking allocated memory for `NULL`?

Comment: Plain old `malloc` is required to return memory aligned to `alignof(max_align_t)` even if the space requested is smaller. That should be plenty of alignment for a short string.

Comment: My instinct (for a non-embedded system) is to reserve an arbitrary initial buffer on the stack (maybe 32KB out of my 8MB limit). That's no-cost, should avoid heap fragmentation, and your final (and only) malloc can be tailor-made and filled with a memcpy.

Answer (score 3):

It is doubtful that the program is so long that it can't all be included, but you have made an effort to comply with the [Code Review guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Just be aware that comments such as `// more logic here` or `// ...` will sometimes get the question votes to close.

**Complexity**
You're a Java programmer so I'm going to assume you understand object oriented programming principles. While the C programming language isn't object oriented, some of the principles can be applied such as the Single Responsibility Principle as applied to functions and modules. Therefore the current function is too complex because it does too much. Input should be in either in the calling function or `next_token()` should consist of 2 functions, one that does input and one that parses the input for tokens.

**Error Handling**
There are 2 kinds of errors that can occur in this program, the first is memory allocation errors and the second is input errors. The `Xalloc()` functions can fail if the system has insufficient memory, while this is rare on modern computers it can still happen, especially in an embedded environment with limited memory. A call to any of the memory allocation functions should always be followed by a test to see if the pointer to the memory is `NULL` or not. If the pointer is `NULL` then the memory allocation failed and somewhere in the code the program has to decide what to do, including reporting the memory allocation error.

```
char* next_token() {
    char* buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(*buf));
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed in next_token");
        return buf;
    }

    char cc;

    // consume leading whitespaces
    while (isspace(cc=getchar())) ;

    buf[0] = cc;
    int i=1;
    int nofs = 1;
    while (!isspace(cc=getchar())) {
        if (i >= BUF_SIZE*nofs) {
            // gracefully extend buffer size
            nofs++;
            buf = realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE*nofs*sizeof(*buf));
            if (buf == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed in next_token");
                return buf;
            }

        }
        buf[i] = cc;
        i++;
    }
    // trim buffer
    buf = realloc(buf, (i+1)*sizeof(*buf));
    if (buf == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed in next_token");
        return buf;
    }

    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

Please note that in the above code I changed `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(*buf)`. This makes the code more maintainable because the type of `buf` can be changed and the memory allocations don't require additional editing.

Input errors: If the user types in a `CTRL-D` on a Unix or Linux system the program will encounter an EOF (end of file) character. It currently can't handle that. This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119083/does-isspace-accept-getchar-values) question covers that in more detail.

**Character Input is Slow**
Character input using `getchar()` is slower than using buffered input and processing character input rather than processing strings after they have been read is slower. Grab as many characters as you can using a fixed size buffer and a call to [fgets(char *buffer, int buffer_size, FILE *stream)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). The function `fgets()` reads a line at a time `buffer_size` can be 1K, 2K or 4K or larger + 1 (most lines will be less than 1K). This reduces the memory allocation involved and reads the input faster. You will need a pointer that points to the string starting point after the token. Using `fgets()` in the main program or in a function that calls the tokenizer will also allow you to handle the EOF situation since `fgets()` only reads until the end of the file as well as the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I'll comment on C style:

````c
#define BUF_SIZE (1 << 10) // approx 2 KiB or 1024 chars
```n
This comment makes no sense.  A `char` in C is, by definition, 1 byte.  `1 << 10` bytes is exactly 1024 `char`s.  I suppose I can understand if you're coming from Java where `char` is a UTF-16 code unit.

```c
char* next_token() {
    char* buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
````

Again, `sizeof(char)` is *defined* to be 1. `malloc(BUF_SIZE)` is sufficient.  If you want your code to be robust against someday using, say, `wchar_t` instead of `char`, then idiomatic practice instead is to do `char* buf = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof *buf);`.

Also, you should verify that `malloc` succeeds.

```c
    char cc;
    // consume leading whitespaces
    while (isspace(cc=getchar())) ;
```

Personally I'd break this up instead of embedding the assignment.

```c
    int nofs = 1;
```

I can't decipher what this variable name means. "No filesytem"? "Number Fs"?  "North of South"?

C is not so archaic that there is some tiny limit on lengths of variable names.  Use descriptive names.

```c
            buf = realloc(buf, BUF_SIZE*nofs*sizeof(char));
```

Others have already mentioned that you should grow your buffer exponentially.

`x = realloc(x, ...)` is an anti-pattern.  Always assign to a temporary variable first; otherwise if `realloc` fails, you've lost your original pointer and will leak the memory.

As with `malloc`, `sizeof(char)` is useless, and you should check for `realloc` failure.

```c
    // trim buffer
    buf = realloc(buf, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Same thing here as before about `realloc`.